# Mongodb $cond with find

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is an example order document I have

```
{numberOfHours: 10, status: “BOOKED”, hidden: true},
{numberOfHours: 5, status: “NOT_BOOKED”,hidden: true},
{numberOfHours: 1, status: “BOOKED”, hidden: true},
{numberOfHours: 10, status: “PENDING”, hidden: true}
```

This is my requirement. I want to find all which are not `hidden(hidden = false)`. But if the status is `“BOOKED”` it should show even if `hidden` is `true`. I will have to use a `collection.find()` as well

This is my query -

```
{  $expr: {
       $eq:[ {
          $cond: {
             if: { "$status" : { $ne: "BOOKED"} },
             then: {"$hidden"},
             else: {null}
           }
       },
       false ] }
}
```

How to proceed from here? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/index.html) to express both conditions:

```
{  $expr: {
       $or: [ { $eq: [ "$status", "BOOKED" ] }, { $eq: [ "$hidden", false ] } ]
}
```

(if status is different than `BOOKED` then it checks whether hidden set to `false`)

Answer (score 2):

```
{$expr: {
    {$cond: {
        "if": {"$eq": ["$status", "BOOKED"]},
        "then": {"$hidden"},
        "else": {null}
      }
    },false}
}
```

Note:- I have given an answer based on your question.
Hope this will help you.